# '<generator object <genexpr> at 0x0000014A76371040>'

Tags: python

trying to  use  if else in a list comprehension
expected output is (23.0,23.3,26.0,27.0,0)
have tried converting the values to float before diving it with ten but still not worki

```
    temps= (230,233,260,270,-999)
    new_temps=((temp)/10 if temp != -999 else 0 for temp in temps)
    print(new_temps)
```

the error I get  is
<generator object  at 0x0000021889021040>

Comment: print(tuple(new_temps))

Comment: `tuple((temp)/10 if temp != -999 else 0 for temp in temps)` or use `*new_temps` unpacking statment

Comment: @Nayah You want output as list or tuple?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Understanding generators in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1756096/understanding-generators-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need to build an intermediate list comprehension, you can pass a generator to the `tuple` function:

```
temps = (230, 233, 260, 270, -999)
new_temps = tuple(temp / 10 if temp != -999 else 0 for temp in temps)
print(new_temps)
```

Comment: How is your answer different from @Inoguier's?

Answer (score 3):

List comprehension is done with `[]`, not `()`, the latter is actually the notation to create a [generator](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators).

To fix that, just change to `[]`:

```py
temps= (230,233,260,270,-999)
new_temps=tuple([(temp)/10 if temp != -999 else 0 for temp in temps])
print(new_temps)
```

But if you do want to use the generator notation, you could do this as well:

```py
temps= (230,233,260,270,-999)
new_temps=tuple((temp/10 if temp != -999 else 0 for temp in temps))
print(new_temps)
```

Comment: Even with generator it is possible to use `*new_temps` uppacking statement

Comment: OP's expected output is tuple as mentioned

Comment: Yaa for permanent storage  that can be done, but nothing is mention

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out, I didn't notice OP wanted a tuple. Just updated the answer.

Comment: No need to create list than convert to tuple, directly pass generator to tuple function

Comment: Case 1(temporary storage): `new_temps=((temp)/10 if temp != -999 else 0 for temp in temps); print(*new_temps)`

Comment: Just included your approach @ExplooreX

Comment: Case 1(Permanent storage): `new_temps=tuple((temp)/10 if temp != -999 else 0 for temp in temps); print(new_temps)`

Answer (score -1):

If you need to print it, you have to convert it to a list.

```
    temps= (230,233,260,270,-999)
    new_temps=list((temp)/10 if temp != -999 else 0 for temp in temps)
    print(new_temps)
```